# Who are the Kimkaras?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, hanuman

In his journey towards the Himalayas to take the Sanjeevni Booti, Lord Hanuman sees the abodes of different Gods. It is described in the [Yuddha Kanda Sarga 74](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddhasans74.htm) in the following verse :

> स ब्रह्मकोशं रजतालयं च |
>   शक्रालयं रुद्रशरप्रमोक्षम् |
>   हयाननं ब्रह्मशिरश्च दीप्तं |
>   ददर्श वैवस्वत **किङ्करांश्** च || ६-७४-५९
>
> sa brahmakośaṃ rajatālayaṃ ca |
>   śakrālayaṃ rudraśarapramokṣam |
>   hayānanaṃ brahmaśiraśca dīptaṃ |
>   dadarśa vaivasvata **kiṅkarāṃś** ca || 6-74-59
>
> He saw the abode of Brahma the lord of creation, Kailasa the abode of Shiva the lord of dissolution, the abode of Indra the lord of celestials, the arrow-discharging place of Rudra, the worshipping place of Hayagriva, the horse-faced form of Vishnu, the shining place at which Brahma's head fell down, the sun-god and **Kimkaras**. [[6-74-59]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddhasans74.htm#Verse59)

Who are the Kimkaras mentioned here? I couldn't find any information elsewhere about them.

Comment: KimKara means those who ask *'what (kim किं) to do (Kar कर)'* that is slaves or servants. Servants ask 'what to do' किं करवाणि or किं करोमि , so they are called KimKara "किंकर" in sanskrit

Comment: @Anurag Singh Interesting interpretation! Do you have any scriptural reference for this etymology, like Nirukta etc.?

Comment: Well it's not my interpretation. It's basic etymology of word. Like here- [कर शब्द Kara](http://sanskritdocuments.org/learning_tools/ashtadhyayi/vyakhya/3/3.2.21.htm) , "किंयत्तद्बहुषु कृञो ऽज्विधानम्। किङ्करा। यत्करा। तत्करा। बहुकरा" - "*by adding Kim, Yat, Tat, Bahu with Karoti (कृ धातु) , KimKara, YatKara, TatKara, BahuKara words are formed*" [that page explains various words like निशां करोति - निशाकर (who does night - moon) , भाः करोति भास्कर (who does light- sun), et cetera. ] . See this - *कामं कथय कल्याणि* ***किंकरः करवाणि किम्॥***  .

Comment: Another example of such words formed by phrases is "मांधाता" . "तदेन्द्रो देशिनीं प्रादात् **मां धास्यति** इत्यवद्वचः।" - *"Indra put his forefinger in mouth of baby, and said he will **feed on (धास्यति) me (माम्)** ."* This is why that baby is called [Maandhaata मांधाता](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandhatri)

Comment: Thanks. I was asking since some words have multiple etymological interpretations in Sanskrit. For instance, Gudakesha, a name of Arjuna, can be interpreted as Guda + Kesha i.e,  curly haired one, or as Gudak + Esha, roughly meaning conquerer of sleep. Many such etymologies have been discussed in the ancient book of etymology, [Nirukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirukta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Sabha Parva - SECTION III-Sabha Kriya Parva Of **[Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02003.htm)**   , Kinkaras are the the race of  fierce, huge-bodied  Rakshasas with coppery eyes and arrowy ears.

In Mahabharata they are said to be guards and protectors of Maya-Sabha ,which  Maya Danava made for Pandavas after the Kahndav Dahana. They were said to be carrying this hall anywhere from their strength. And their Number was 8000.

> तां सम तत्र मयेनॊक्ता रक्षन्ति च वहन्ति च |
>   सभाम अष्टौ सहस्राणि
>   **किंकरा नाम राक्षसाः** || 25||
>  अन्तरिक्षचरा घॊरा महाकाया महाबलाः|
>   रक्ताक्षाः पिङ्गलाक्षाश च शुक्तिकर्णाः परहारिणः ||26||
>
> Maya built was so wide, delightful, and refreshing, and composed of
>   such excellent materials, and furnished with such golden walls and
>   archways, and adorned with so many varied pictures, and was withal so
>   rich and well-built, that in beauty it far surpassed Sudharma of the
>   Dasarha race, or the mansion of Brahma himself. **And eight thousand
>   Rakshasas called Kinkaras, fierce, huge-bodied and endued with great
>   strength, of red coppery eyes and arrowy ears, well-armed and capable
>   of ranging through the air, used to guard and protect that palace.**

---

There is also a brief mentioning of Kinkara again in Adi Parva.

Mahabharata -  Book 1: Adi Parva - SECTION CLXXVIII - [**Chaitraratha Parva**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01179.htm)   - Tells us that a Rakshasa called Kinkara entered into King kalmashapada's Body on order of Rishi  Vishwamitra.

> Viswamitra, ascertaining the disposition of the king (and fearing that
>   the difference might be made up), ordered a Rakshasa to enter the body
>   of the king. And a Rakshasa of the name of Kinkara then entered the
>   monarch's body in obedience to Saktri's curse and Viswamitra's
>   command.  **p. 358**

So it looks like they were race of Rakshasas in the command of Maya-Danava and were capable to fly in the air and to lift huge loads.

Answer (score 2):

[Kimkaras](http://www.kasarabada.org/ramayanam%2069S.html) were demons sent by Ravana to kill Hanuman after he destroyed the Ashoka vatika:

> The destruction of part of Ashokvan is conveyed to Ravan by the
>   terrified Rakshasa Women. Immediately Ravana dispatches Rakshasa
>   warriors by name Kimkaras. Hanuman kills all of them immediately. He
>   lets go a victory roar reciting the famous Jayamantram ! After hearing
>   about the death of Kimkaras Ravan sends the son of Prahasta with
>   orders to capture Hanuman.

[image]

> Hearing the words of the Rakshasa women , becoming extremely angry the
>   powerful Ravana then ordered the Kimkaras to capture Hanuman.

Comment: Kinkaras are not rakshasas. They are just servants or slaves.

Comment: Read the attached sanskrit shloka please.

Comment: I read it before commenting. Thanks. I am saying literal meaning. Kinkara means a servants or minions. Here, they are the servants of Ravana, who are Rakshasas. Kinkara is not a proper noun like Gandharva or Yaksha. There are even kinkaras to Yama. Here, they mean servant to Yama. It changes with respect to the context. In the context given in the question, they are not servants of Rakshasa because most of them are killed. Hanuman could not see them near Badrinath becuase if they exist, they should be in Lanka. Hence, they are different than you said in the answer.